# Why javascript Map() object is empty when passed from frontend?

Tags: javascript

I use this code when make a request to server. Inside request function i do this:

```
const menu = this.props.location.state.menuItemDishesMap; //get Map() value from props
const order = {
  person: { id: 1 },
  menuItemDishMap: menu, //pass it to order object that goes to server
};

console.log(order); //make sure that my Map() object went to server
```

This is what `console.log()` says:

[image: console.log]

But, when I see developer tools, this Map() is always empty.

[image: developer tools]

Have no idea why.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Please show us how you are sending the request.

Comment: @connexo Actually I was pretty sure it would turn out to be a duplicate of [How do you JSON.stringify an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29085197/1048572). There's definitely no async code in the question.

Comment: this is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54140811/13334444 thanks everybody!