# How to send big set of JSON data from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to make a response that sends a big data of `JSON`. So `JSON.stringify()` seems not to work because let's say I have an object:

```
const student = {
  somevar: 15,
  anothervar: 21,
  setofdata: Map(15) {
    1 => {
      somevar: 31, 
      anothervar: 45
    }
    2... 15
  }
}
```

So what happens when I convert it to string will be like this: `{'somevar': '15', 'anothervar': '21', 'setofdata': {}}`

Now when I parse it back, it seems like he doesn't know all about inside the set of data. What module should I download to achieve this? I tried [LJSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ljson) but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, `student` contains a `Map` object, which is stringified to `"{}"`.

A quick work-around would be to convert it to a flat object first:

```js
const student = {
  somevar: 15,
  anothervar: 21,
  setofdata: new Map([[0, 'hello'], [1, 'world']])
}

const normalized = {...student, setofdata: Object.fromEntries(student.setofdata)};

console.log(JSON.stringify(normalized))
```

If you wish to use a more generic and profound solution, take a looke here:

[How do you JSON.stringify an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map)

It suggests a way to customize the serialization, specifically for maps (can be also implemented on special js values like NaN, Infinity and others)