# Javascript - How to get the size in bytes of a Map

Tags: javascript

How can I get the size in bytes of the following Map?

```
const cache = new Map();
cache.set("1", { id: "1" });
```

Comment: What do you mean size in bytes? In your example, what is the expected result?

Comment: I wanna see how much RAM does it use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map object does not define default stringification, that is, `JSON.stringify` will not work on it by default, nor `mapObj.toString()` will return a meaningful answer. Therefore, you need to define how to turn a Map to a string, so that you can estimate its size.

Building on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map):

```js
function mapSize(oMap){
    function replacer(key, value) {
      if(value instanceof Map) {
        return {
          dataType: 'Map',
          value: [...value],
        };
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(oMap, replacer).length;
}

let test= new Map([["a",2],["b",3]]);
console.log(mapSize(test)); //44
```

This will return something you can use to approximate. Beware that 'dataType' and 'value' fields are arbitrary,  and they effect the 'size'.