# Typescript Generic Map type not able to set KVP

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a generic Map in typescript but no KVPs are getting set in the map.

```
class type1 {
    public prop1: string;
}

var t1: type1 = {
    prop1: '1'
};

var t2: type1 = {
    prop1: '2'
};

let map = new Map<string, type1>();
map.set('1', t1);
map.set('2', t2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
console.log(JSON.stringify(map['1']));
console.log(JSON.stringify(map['2']));
```

Console Output:

- "{}"
- undefined
- undefined

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as if it's a plain object but that's wrong. `map.get('1')` to get the value for `'1'` and as for serialising: [How do you JSON.stringify an ES6 Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29085197)