# Printing/Logging Set

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In all the examples of new Set it shows how to convert array to set, add to set, etc and then shows what to expect when using console.log . Is there a difference with Google Apps Script? Seems so simple, not sure what Im missing?

```
function myFunction() {
  let arr = ["one", "two", "three"]
  let setTest = new Set(arr)
  Logger.log(setTest)
  // Output: 
//Info  {}
}
```

The following example shows how to create a new Set from an array.

```
let chars = new Set(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c']);
```

All elements in the set must be unique therefore the chars only contains 3 distinct elements a, b and c.

```
console.log(chars);
```

Output:

```
Set { 'a', 'b', 'c' }
```

Comment: what if you do `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(setTest))` ? maybe it's the toString version of the Set which has a problem

Comment: If you want to print a set, you need to spread the values into an array and convert it to JSON. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73989963/1762224

Comment: also, you have the `size` attribute that you can print on a Set to see how many elements are in there.

Comment: I don't understand your question `setTest` is a Set object.  What do you want to do with `setTest`?

Comment: @ValLeNain .size prints 3

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl from Array is how I have been viewing, Im just curious why alot of the examples and training show you should be able to console.log the Set. Trying to understand

Comment: @TheWizEd Just learning about Set and arrays. From all the training and documentation it shows you can just print the Set contents. I was adding and deleting things so just as I go along I wanted to check what was it contained, etc

Comment: Still not understanding your question.  The Set object has a `toString()` method that is called by default if you want to display the object.  For Chrome it will appear as an object `{ 'a', 'b', 'c' }` .  See [Set Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: @TheWizEd If I try to display, I get `{}` Im trying to do the same in the link you posted as `console.log(mySet1)
// logs Set(5) [ 1, "some text", {…}, {…}, 5 ] in Firefox
// logs Set(5) { 1, "some text", {…}, {…}, 5 } in Chrome`

Comment: If you are using Chrome that is the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  let arr = ["one", "two", "three"]
  let s = new Set(arr);
  let it = s.values;
  Logger.log([...s])
}

Execution log
11:52:44 AM Notice  Execution started
11:52:45 AM Info    [one, two, three]
11:52:46 AM Notice  Execution completed
```