# Sending a map from JS to Rust does not arrive

Tags: javascript, rust, serde, tauri

I have a small tauri app that on the JS part sends some data back to the rust backend using the `invoke` method.

The method works, most of the data arrives to the backend. The data itself contains a map, which does not arrive though.

```js
const [details, setDetails] = useState({
    name: "",
    country: "",
    address: "",
    items: new Map<String, number>
})
...
async function handleSubmit(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(details)
    await invoke('submit_new_customer', { details }).then((submitted) => { ... })
}
```

The logged out details:

```js
{
    name: "Alfred Gustavsson",
    country: "Norway",
    address: "Exapmle street",
    items: Map(1) {'3' => 1}
}
```

The backend:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct NewCustomerInput {
    name: String,
    country: String,
    address: Option<String>,
    items: HashMap<String, usize>
}

#[tauri::command]
fn submit_new_customer(details: NewCustomerInput) -> bool {
    println!("{:?}", details);
    ...
```

From the print I can see that the items is `{}`. How can I setup my struct to accept the Map from the fronted?

Comment: Please show us some JS code which sends the (constant) NewCustomerInput that you described. Alternatively, show us some wireshark or webserver logging which reveals exactly how `items` got serialized when it went out on the wire.

Comment: Maps have no built-in serialization. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map

Comment: @J_H it is a tauri app, it never goes out to the network. I added some JS code.

Comment: @ray Thanks a lot, I just changed it to an object and now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you will need to convert your `Map` into an `Object`, prior to sending:

```js
const mapToObj = (map) => Object.fromEntries([...map.entries()]);

const objToMap = (obj) => new Map(Object.entries(obj));

const serializableDetails = (details) => {
    const { name, address, country, items } = details;
    return { name, address, country, items: mapToObj(items) }
}

const jsDetails = {
    name: 'Joe Biden',
    address: '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500',
    country: 'USA',
    items: objToMap({ foo: 1, bar: 2 }) 
}

console.log(jsDetails); // Note: the Map will not show in the snippet console

const postDetails = serializableDetails(jsDetails);

console.log(postDetails);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Usage

```js
async function handleSubmit(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault()
    await invoke('submit_new_customer', {
        details: serializableDetails(details); // pre-process here
    })
        .then((submitted) => { ... })
}
```