# JSON stringify a Set

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

How would one [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)?

Things that did not work in Chromium 43:

```
var s = new Set(['foo', 'bar']);

JSON.stringify(s); // -> "{}"
JSON.stringify(s.values()); // -> "{}"
JSON.stringify(s.keys()); // -> "{}"
```

I would expect to get something similar to that of a serialized array.

```
JSON.stringify(["foo", "bar"]); // -> "["foo","bar"]"
```

Comment: closely related: [How do I persist a ES6 Map in localstorage (or elsewhere)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28918232/1048572)

Answer (score 197, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` doesn't directly work with sets because the data stored in the set is not stored as properties.

But you can convert the set to an array. Then you will be able to stringify it properly.

Any of the following will do the trick:

```js
JSON.stringify([...s]);
JSON.stringify([...s.keys()]);
JSON.stringify([...s.values()]);
JSON.stringify(Array.from(s));
JSON.stringify(Array.from(s.keys()));
JSON.stringify(Array.from(s.values()));
```

Comment: I was gonna propose `Array.from()`. But this looks idiomically better.

Comment: Just to add some reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) has some examples of this and other related techniques

Comment: A list comprehension could work as well: `JSON.stringify([_ for (_ of s)])`

Comment: All great ways of doing it, sadly they don't work in Chromium 43 out of the box as spread and Array.from are not yet implemented. Looks like Babel to the rescue.

Comment: @MitMaro You can enable chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony

Comment: A current proposal to improve the default of `Set.prototype.toJSON`: https://github.com/DavidBruant/Map-Set.prototype.toJSON

Comment: I'm so pleased with the order in which you presented those lines of code: sorted mostly by length, but grouping the `...` approaches together.  Perfect!

Comment: But then you lose all the advantages of using a set in first place, it just converts it to array.

Comment: This works if you're trying to stringify a `Set` directly. However, if the `Set` is not "top level", then you're better off using [replacers as explained by tanguy_k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491780/114558).

Answer (score 84):

You can pass a "replacer" function to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
const fooBar = {
  foo: new Set([1, 2, 3]),
  bar: new Set([4, 5, 6])
};

JSON.stringify(
  fooBar,
  (_key, value) => (value instanceof Set ? [...value] : value)
);
```

Result:

```
"{"foo":[1,2,3],"bar":[4,5,6]}"
```

*`toJSON` is a legacy artifact, and a better approach is to use a custom `replacer`*, see https://github.com/DavidBruant/Map-Set.prototype.toJSON/issues/16

Comment: there is shorten version in ES6 `JSON.stringify(fooBar, (key, value) => value instanceof Set ? [...value] : value)`

Comment: The corresponding reviver is left as an exercise for the reader? ;-)

Comment: Will you please incorporate the comment from @OzzyCzech into the answer? It's a fantastic modern solution.

Comment: This is a very nice way of dealing with deep sets to save more nasty iterations. Well done

Comment: I'm not sure why this is so popular, when you can't get Sets back easily from this?   If you parse that result and try `parsed.foo.add(1)` ... it dies, because an array does't have an `add` function.

Comment: For anyone else coming here later wondering how to get a Set back from this, `JSON.parse` takes an equivalent function called `reviver` that's run on everything it parses. I ended up solving this by adding `"__isSet"` to the start of any array made out of a set and then checking for this in the reviver function, turning it back into a set when found.

Comment: For reviver (& Map), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150320/9549068

Answer (score 14):

While all of the above work I suggest that you subclass set and add a `toJSON` method to make sure that it stringify's correctly. Especially if you are going to be stringifying often. I use sets in my Redux stores and needed to make sure this was never a problem.

This is a basic implementation. Naming is just to illustrate the point pick your own style.

```
class JSONSet extends Set {
    toJSON () {
        return [...this]
    }
}

const set = new JSONSet([1, 2, 3])
console.log(JSON.stringify(set))
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach as `toJSON` is considered a legacy feature. A proposal to add `toJSON` to both `set` and `map` was rejected: https://github.com/DavidBruant/Map-Set.prototype.toJSON/issues/16

Comment: Overriding `constructor` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with all the previous approaches is that they all convert the set into Array, which is missing the entire point of Set and indexes.

What you should do is to use an Object instead.
Either convert it with the following function or simply create it as Object instead of Set.

```
const mySet = new Set(['hello', 'world']);
const myObj = {};
for (let value of mySet.values()) {
  myObj[value] = true;
}
```

Then instead of using `mySet.has('hello')`
Do `myObj.hasOwnProperty('hello')`.

Then stringify it as an object without a problem.

**Note**:
The following method uses more memory because it needs to store the value as well as the key.
But performence wise it's still O(1) compared to Array.includes() which is O(n) and miss the point of even using a Set.