# Javascript Replace item if key is duplicate and sort and delete except last 2 items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array like below , I want to sort it by key and then remove everything except last 2 items  and delete remaining.

```
var status = new Array();
status.push({key: 'BOB', value: 10});
status.push({key: 'TOM', value: 3});
status.push({key: 'ROB', value: 22});
status.push({key: 'JON', value: 7});
```

If I again push below with duplicate key  for example :

```
status.push({key: 'BOB', value: 20});
```

I need following output , how do i achieve this in javascript.

```
[
  {
    "key": "BOB",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "key": "TOM",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "ROB",
    "value": 22
  },
  {
    "key": "JON",
    "value": 7
  }
]
```

Note : I need to sort this by key later.

Edit : If I have object like this , How do i sort by keys ? and get only last 2 items and delete remaining.

```
var status = new Object();
status['BOB'] = 10
status['TOM'] = 3
status['ROB'] = 22
status['JON'] = 7
```

Comment: Why are you using an array instead of an object whose keys are the names? That will do this automatically.

Comment: Before pushing the new value, search the array to see if the key already exists. If it does, replace it.

Comment: I want to sort it later by key , I guess thats not possible in object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.push() and unique items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719477/array-push-and-unique-items)

Comment: @Graciewilliams you can get and array from Object.keys or Object.items and sort when you need to.

Comment: @G.aziz That question leaves the old object alone, it doesn't replace it.

Comment: @g.aziz that duplicate sounds promising, but the answers to it are not.

Comment: You may want to look at [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It won't solve the problem of replacing, but it's like an object, and you can get sorted keys a bit easier.

Comment: I have edited my question with objects , but in stack overflow ,they tell we cannot sort - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788051/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-value

Comment: What are you doing with the keys/values that you need to sort them? You can get all of the keys as an array and sort them, then get the values...

Comment: Yea seems like two steps , I actually need to sort them and remove first two items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an array, use an object:

```js
(function () {
  var status = {};
  status['BOB'] = 10;
  status['TOM'] = 3;
  status['ROB'] = 22;
  status['JON'] = 7;
  status['BOB'] = 20;
  // convert to array
  var output = Object.keys(status)
    // sort by key
    .sort()
    // keep last two after sorting
    .slice(-2)
    // convert [key, value] to { key, value }
    .map(function (key) {
      return { key: key, value: status[key] };
    });

  console.log(output);
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: Thank you works smooth , How do I remove everything except last 2 after sorting ?

Comment: See @Triptych answer , he sorted it

Comment: @Graciewilliams see [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Description), [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties) and finally [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes). His answer is wrong. If you want guaranteed iteration order of keys, use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), not an object.

Comment: I used something like  myObject.set('@', 2);  , but i push items randomly on ajax request ,so cannot push in order , I gotta sort it some how later , then remove except last two items.

Comment: @Graciewilliams better?

Comment: What about @dota2pro answer ? he was able to do it with array

Comment: Never said you _couldn't_ do it with an array, just that you _shouldn't_. Replacing an entry in an array based on a key in the object entry is cumbersome and inefficient. Replacing a property on an object is a simple assignment that occurs in approximately constant time. You're welcome to accept whatever answer works best for you though.

Comment: I want optimal solution ,  I mean u sorted and u sliced like I asked , will urs work just in chrome latest ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams if you replace `const` with `var`, my answer works all the way back to internet explorer 9. If you polyfill `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.map()`, my answer would then even work on browsers such as netscape. Browser compatibility will not be an issue.

Comment: When i change to var , I get this - [ { "key": "8", "value": "O" }, { "key": "9", "value": "b" } ]

Comment: I am just confused , u told u cannot sort object , so how is ur answer working perfectly ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams The problem was that [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) conflicted with a global variable declaration. Putting the code in an IIFE fixes that. I'm also not sorting an object, I'm sorting an array. Please read the comments and study the code.

Comment: I want to slice status , because there are 100's of data coming every second.status count is keep increasing.

Comment: @Graciewilliams you're conflating two different problems. If you want the last 2 values _sorted by key_, you need to keep all of the properties anyway. If you want the last 2 _recently used_ values, then that's an entirely different question than what you've asked.

Comment: :( sorry , but my question has this point - delete except last 2 items

Comment: "last 2 items" _sorted by what criteria_? You've already specified _sorted by key_, which requires you to keep all the properties in order to determine what the last 2 items of _all the data_ sorted by key is. I'm not editing my answer, and you shouldn't edit your question at this point since several people have already sufficiently answered the question you already asked. Ask a new question and make sure to be very specific about your desired output so you don't waste people's time again.

Comment: Ok will post new question

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `Map` rather than an array or an object. Maps are like objects [but with some important differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared).

```js
// initialize the map
var stats = new Map([['BOB',10],['TOM',3],['ROB',22],['JON',7]]);
// set a specific key's value
stats.set('BOB', 20);
// sort by key
var keys = Array.from(stats.keys());
keys.sort();
// get the last two
keys = keys.slice(-2);
// map the remaining keys to the desired structure
var result = keys.map(key => { 
  return { 
    key: key, 
    value: stats.get(key) 
  }; 
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: status map count is increasing everytime i use set , if i use var stats instead var result  , will it work  ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams I'm not sure what you mean. I just updated to use the variable name `stats` instead of `status` to get around the `window.status` issue. The `result` variable simply holds the new structure (an array of objects with key and value properties).

Comment: I mean if do console.log(stats) again after slice , it should have same content of result... and reuse it again , because I am getting 100's of data every second ,

Comment: This answer, like the others, answers the question posed. If you have further requirements which you did not mention in this question, please, ask a new question and make sure you mention all of the requirements up front.

Comment: I think its better to use set instead of a map since A set is a collection of items which are unique i.e no element can be repeated

Comment: @dota2pro a map has unique keys, and it provides a mapping from each key to a respective value. A set does not have that capability, and your answer using `Set` is completely wrong. Try logging `stats`, and also what `keys` is before you slice, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: According to https://javascript.info/map-set-weakmap-weakset Map is a collection of keyed data items, just like an Object. But the main difference is that Map allows keys of any type.

A Set is a collection of values, where each value may occur only once.

Do you have any source for your info ?

Comment: @dota2pro [`Map` key equality algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Key_equality) ensures that no duplicate keys exist in a `Map`. It's the [exact same algorithm that `Set` uses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Value_equality) for its values.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it the way others are suggesting you should use a [set](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-javascript/) set always have unique elements in them

```js
// initialize the map
var stats = new Set([['BOB',10],['TOM',3],['ROB',22],['JON',7]]);
// set a specific key's value
stats.add('BOB', 20);
// sort by key
var keys = Array.from(stats.keys());
keys.sort();
// get the last two
keys = keys.slice(-2);
// map the remaining keys to the desired structure
var result = keys
console.log(result);
```

I think this answers all your questions

```js
let status1 = [];
status1.push({
    key: 'BOB',
    value: 10
}, {
    key: 'TOM',
    value: 3
}, {
    key: 'ROB',
    value: 22
}, {
    key: 'JON',
    value: 7
});

console.log('Initial array', status1);

//const newItem = {
//  key: 'BOB',
//  value: 20
//};

const newItem = {
    key: 'BOB',
    value: 99
};

for (let i = 0; i < status1.length; i++) {

    if (status1[i].key === newItem.key) {
        status1[i] = newItem;
    }

}

Array.prototype.inArray = function(comparer) { 
    for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++) { 
        if(comparer(this[i])) return true; 
    }
    return false; 
}; 
Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(element, comparer) { 
    if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
        this.push(element);
    }
}; 

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist 

status1.pushIfNotExist(newItem, function(e) { 
    return e.key === newItem.key; 
});

console.log('after push', status1);

function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        var x = a[key];
        var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}

sortByKey(status1, 'key');
console.log('AFter sort', status1);

console.log('Last item', status1[status1.length - 1]);
console.log('Second Last item', status1[status1.length - 2]);
```

Comment: Ok , what if I push something which does not already exists ? I think u dont have condition for it

Comment: added if (status1["key"] === undefined) { // if doesnt exist

Comment: `status1["key"] === undefined` is _always_ true. If you were to change `BOT` back to `BOB` you would then have the first entry replaced and a new entry added with the same key.

Comment: And now you're modifying the array prototype which just opens up a whole different can of worms...

Answer (score 0):

In the case you decide to keep the array of objects structure, you can implement a method using [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) this way:

```js
const pushWithCheck = (arr, obj) =>
{
    let idx = arr.findIndex(({key}) => key === obj.key);

    if (idx >= 0)
        arr.splice(idx, 1, obj);
    else
        arr.push(obj);
}

var _status = [];
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'BOB', value: 10});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'TOM', value: 3});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'ROB', value: 22});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'JON', value: 7});
console.log("Before duplicated key:", _status);
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'BOB', value: 20});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'ROB', value: 99});
console.log("After duplicated key:", _status);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Now, to sort by the `key` property of the objects and get last `2` elements, you can use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with a negative (`-2`) argument, like this:

```js
const pushWithCheck = (arr, obj) =>
{
    let idx = arr.findIndex(({key}) => key === obj.key);

    if (idx >= 0)
        arr.splice(idx, 1, obj);
    else
        arr.push(obj);
}

// Generate the _status array.
var _status = [];
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'BOB', value: 10});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'TOM', value: 3});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'ROB', value: 22});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'JON', value: 7});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'BOB', value: 20});
pushWithCheck(_status, {key: 'ROB', value: 99});
console.log("_status is: ", _status);

// Sort the _status array by ascending.
let sorted = _status.slice().sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key));

// Get last two elements of the sorted array.
let lastTwo = sorted.slice(-2);

console.log("Sorted is: ", sorted);
console.log("Last two elements are: ", lastTwo);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```