# cannot use "Set" in a session variable express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I was trying to use Set as a session value, but for some reason I got this unexpected result. I'm making two requests from the client to this route.

```
app.post("/api/add_to_cart", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.productList);
    if (req.session.productList === undefined)
        req.session.productList = new Set();
    console.log(req.session.productList);
    req.session.productList.add('one');
    console.log(req.session.productList);
    res.send();
});
```

output:

```
undefined
Set(0) {}
Set(1) { 'one' }

{}
{}
TypeError: req.session.productList.add is not a function
```

But if I use array insted of Set it works as expected

```
app.post("/api/add_to_cart", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.productList);
    if (req.session.productList === undefined)
        req.session.productList = [];
    console.log(req.session.productList);
    req.session.productList.push('one');
    console.log(req.session.productList);
    res.send();
});
```

output:

```
undefined
[]
[ 'one' ]

[ 'one' ]
[ 'one' ]
[ 'one', 'one' ]
```

For some unknown reason the Set object is being changed to {}.

Comment: Which [store implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) are you using? How does it serialise and deserialise session state?

Comment: Every thing is set to default, I have not added any store implementation. It's just what you see and the initilization with only the secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession):

> ##### `req.session`
>
> To store or access session data, simply use the request property
> `req.session`, which is **(generally) serialized as JSON** by the store,
> so nested objects are typically fine.
> <sub>(highlighting mine)</sub>

…and [`Set`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31190885/1048572)/[`Map`s do not support JSON (de)serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28918232/1048572) out of the box.

The builtin development-only `MemoryStore` [does](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/0048bcac451ad867299d404aca94c79cc8bc751d/session/memory.js#L120) [this](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/0048bcac451ad867299d404aca94c79cc8bc751d/session/memory.js#L171-L172) as well.