# Unmarshall of string set in DynamoDB fails

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, unmarshalling

I have tried to `marshall` DynamoDB's `String Set` and `unmarshall` it back as below.

```
import {marshall, unmarshall} from '@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb';

test('Marshall and Unmarshall Test', () => {
  const raw = {
    'anArray': new Set([
      'Apple',
      'Mango'
    ])
  };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(marshall(raw)));
  // {"anArray":{"SS":["Apple","Mango"]}}

  const marshalledResult = marshall(raw);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(unmarshall(marshalledResult)));
  // {"anArray":{}}

});
```

But I am not able to get the `String Set` back. How should we be doing this when we should get a `String Set` from dynamo db and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unmarshall` is the right approach.  I believe you are not seeing the expected result because `JSON.stringify` [does not play nicely with sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190885/json-stringify-a-set).  Try logging the unmarshalled result directly:

```js
const unmarshalled = unmarshall(marshalledResult)
console.log(unmarshalled);
// => { anArray: Set(2) { 'Apple', 'Mango' } }
```

Comment: Great observation!!! Changed it to a list using `[...unmarshalled]` and this looks great :)