# Code generated by openapi-generator always sends empty arrays when uniqueItems = true in openapi documentation

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc, openapi-generator-cli

I made a REST endpoint and an open-api documentation for it using SpringDoc+Swagger. Request body of endpoint has a field - set of objects. As I see in generated documentation, it's the same thing as array, except the `uniqueItems` field:

```json
  "fooSet": {
    "uniqueItems": true,
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Foo"
    }
  }
```

Frontend dev uses openapitools/openapi-generator-cli to interact with my endpoint using open-api docs. This lib enforces him to use JS Set in this case. But it cannot serialize Set properly! The openapi-generator-cli generated this code for serialization:
[image: openapi-generator-cli generated code for serialization]
JSON.stringify returns empty array for any Set: [JSON stringify a Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190885/json-stringify-a-set)

1. How can frontend dev customize set serialization? Without editing generated code manually, of course
2. How can I disable `uniqueItems` for all Sets without having to replace all of them to Lists, or add annotation on each Set in each DTO?

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11746. Try the workaround mentioned in the comments there (specifically, mapping Set to Array via type mappings).

Comment: Thank you, Helen. I think you're right, I'll try this workaround later. 
I wonder how it's even possible that such critical bug exists so long in so popular library

Answer (score 0):

As Helen commented, the problem could be solved by mapping Set to Array via type mappings in gradle task:  github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11746

The other solution I found is to remove `uniqueItems` flag manually in `OpenApiCustomiser`:

```kotlin
override fun customise(openApi: OpenAPI) {
    openApi.components.schemas.forEach { customSchema ->
        customSchema.value.properties.values
            .forEach {
                if (it.uniqueItems == true) {
                    it.uniqueItems = null
                }
            }
    }
}
```