# Javascript set does not get returned in expressJs Json response

Tags: javascript, json, express, http, set

I'm trying to return a simple set in the response.

```
const mySet1 = new Set();
mySet1.add(1);
console.log("mySet1", mySet1);
res.status(200).json({ my_set: mySet1 });
```

Even though, it gets logged correctly in the console:

> mySet1 Set(1) { 1 }

In POSTMAN, this is what I see:

```
{
    "my_set": {}
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Maybe coerce the set to an array: `{ my_set: [...mySet1] }`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190885/json-stringify-a-set