# How to deep stringify the following object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following object

```
 const resultAnalytic: ExportAnalyticsData = {
            document: {
                ownerIsExporting: false,
                hasBeenExported: false
            },
            text: {
                fontsUsed: new Array<string>(),
                fontsSizesUsed: new Array<number>(),
                scriptsProfileMapping: new Map([
                    ["Latin", 3],
                    ["English", 3]
                ]),
                numberOfTextObjects: 3,
                numberOfNeuralTextObjects: new Map([
                    ["preset", 2],
                    ["user_generated", 4]
                ]),
                autoHeightTextCount: 3,
                autoWidthTextCount: 1,
                magicTextCount: 0,
                hasCustomFonts: true,
                hasOutlineEffect: true,
                hasPremiumFonts: true,
                hasFreeFonts: true,
                outlineColorsUsed: new Array<string>("red", "blue", "green"),
                outlineThicknessUsed: new Array<number>(2, 3, 4, 5),
                hasArtisticShadow: false,
                hasShapeEffect: false
            },
            image: {
                usedFilters: new Set<string>(),
                usedAdjustments: new Set<string>(),
                usedEraseToolBrushes: true,
                usedRemoveBackground: false,
                uploadedImageCount: 6,
                photosId: new Set<string>(),
                photosStatus: { free: 1, premium: 1 },
                usedTextToImageKeywords: new Set<string>(),
                usedTextToImageStyles: new Set<string>(),
                textToImageContentType: "",
                usedCropOptions: new Set<string>(["option1", "option2", "option3"])
            },
            video: {
                ids: new Set<string>(),
                status: { free: 0, premium: 2 },
                userUploadedVideoCount: 3
            },
            audio: {
                ids: new Set<string>(),
                status: { free: 1, premium: 3 },
                voiceOverClipCount: 4,
                voiceOverClipsDuration: [2, 3, 6, 78],
                userUploadedAudioCount: 3
            },
            designAsset: {
                ids: new Set<string>(),
                status: { free: 2, premium: 4 }
            },
            background: {
                ids: new Set<string>(),
                status: { free: 0, premium: 2 }
            },
            textLockup: {
                ids: new Set<string>(),
                status: { free: 2, premium: 1 }
            },
            shapes: {
                ids: new Set<string>(),
                status: { free: 2, premium: 0 }
            },
            icons: {
                ids: new Set<string>(),
                status: { free: 2, premium: 0 }
            },
            template: {
                ids: new Set<string>(),
                status: { free: 2, premium: 4 }
            },
            temporalArtboard: {
                task: new Array<string>()
            },
            specialGroups: {
                typeOfCounts: new Map([["text_lockup", 7]])
            },
            colors: {
                appliedColors: new Map([
                    ["Text", "#ffffffff_#000000ff"],
                    ["TextShape", "#ffffffff"]
                ]),
                palette: new Set<string>()
            },
            groups: {
                groups: 0,
                timedGroups: 0,
                groupsWithVideo: new Set<Entity>()
            },
            animation: {
                usedEffectCategories: new Set<string>(["in", "out"]),
                usedEffectIds: new Set<string>(["fade-in", "fade-out"]),
                count: 0
            },
            timeline: {
                frameRate: ["0.03", "0.03"],
                duration: ["12.12", "5.6"],
                numberOfScenes: [2, 2],
                resolution: ["100x100", "100x100"]
            },
            videoRemoveBackground: {
                count: 3
            },
            videoSpeedChanged: {
                count: 4
            },
            hasPremiumContent: { hasPremiumElements: true },
            hdrVideo: {
                count: 3
            },
            grid: {
                grids: 3,
                cells: 14,
                images: 7,
                videos: 1
            },
            libraryAsset: {
                assetTypes: {
                    image: 4,
                    color: 0,
                    font: 0
                }
            }
        };
```

How can I call JSON stringify on it so that I can save it as a string? I need to do so to store it as metadata in a document.

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.stringify(resultAnalytic)`? What happened?

Comment: btw set,maps are not part of json

Comment: @mykaf It doesn't go deep enough. It misses some of the values

Comment: Can you include the JSON that is returned? Is it specifically missing the sets and maps? If so, create those beforehand, then convert to arrays or objects before including them in your overarching object.

Comment: not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491780/13583510 will help

Comment: Related:  [how to JSON.stringify a Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190885/json-stringify-a-set)

Comment: Is there one function that can help me deep stringify the whole object above?

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) _Only enumerable own properties are visited. This means Map, Set, etc. will become "{}". You can use the `replacer` parameter to serialize them to something more useful. ..._

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no one function you will have to write explicit serialization code.

Comment: maybe `const customReplacer = (key, value) => value instanceof Set ? [...value] : value instanceof Map ? Object.fromEntries(value) : value;` and `JSON.stringify(resultAnalytic, customReplacer)`