# string to map object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var map = new Map();
map.set('key1','value1');
map.set('key2','value2');

console.log(map);
console.log(map.toString());
console.log(JSON.parse(map.toString()))
//Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Converted map object to string using `toString()` and now I am unable to convert to map object from string.

Comment: “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1” means that whatever you’re trying to parse is usually `[object Object]`, though in this case `[object Map]`.

Comment: Is this `[object Map]` a valid JSON?

Comment: Hint: If it says "`[object Map]`", there isn't any more magical information hidden there. "`[object Map]`" is literally the string you're trying to parse here, from which you'll obviously never get your `value1` and `value2` back.

Comment: @Rajesh how to do that to string again? I only tried with JSON.parse

Comment: Map's are not JSON compatible, this is because the key can be anything, including objects etc.  If your using simple key value / pairs, it might be easier to use  `Object.create(null)` instead.

Comment: @deceze I want to make a string from map object and convert that string again to map? How can it be possible?

Comment: More info on stringifying/parsing maps in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918232/how-do-i-persist-a-es6-map-in-localstorage-or-elsewhere

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To store a stringified result, better to use plain JSON object, however using `Map` you can create a array of entries and stringify that

```
var str = JSON.stringify(Array.from( map.entries()));
```

and then again you can parse the JSON string to array and construct a new `Map`

```
var map = new Map(JSON.parse(str))
```

```js
var map1 = new Map();
map1.set('key1','value1');
map1.set('key2','value2');

var str = JSON.stringify(Array.from( map1.entries()));

//store the string somewhere or pass it to someone
//or however you want to carry it

//re construct the map again
var map2 = new Map(JSON.parse(str))

console.log('key1', map2.get('key1'));
console.log('key2', map2.get('key2'));
```

However, `Array.from(map)`, or using will also return the same thing and can be used here, but someone cannot grantee what it's actually returns until execute it, on the other hand, getting an Iterator and then forming an array is more conventional and readable, however Array.from(map) might be a better solution. Also `spread operator` can be used over **map** `[...map]` or **map.entries()** `[...map.entries()]` to form the same array of entries.

Comment: I'm amazed at Javascript for once, this is almost valid English… "JSON-stringify array from map entries".

Comment: Nice solution, may I suggest you make into a Snippet.

Comment: Oh, sure, let me edit. That will be more helpful to others :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because the map.toString() prints `[object Map]` which is not parsable by JSON.parse

You should use `JSON.stringify` to achieve your objective

Corrected script

```js
var map = new Map().set('key1','value1')
.set('key2','value2');

console.log(map);
//since the underlying type is array requires to be expanded [...map]
console.log(JSON.stringify([...map])); 

map2 = new Map(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...map])));
```

Remember: Maps are immutable objects, and the underlying type is an array, you have to reassign the map variable or chain the sets functions.

Full explanation can be found here: http://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html

Comment: I corrected it. Though it highlights that this doesn't work…

Comment: this results in an empty object ... how is this useful :p

Comment: just edited now, sorry you are too fast guys :D :D :D, please remove downvote, now it is correct

Comment: *Almost…* The result is an array, not a Map.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var map = new Map();
map.set('key1','value1');
map.set('key2','value2');

console.log(map);
//Covert your map object into JSON object
var jsonObj=[];

map.forEach(function(val,key){
var tempObj={};
tempObj[key]=val;
jsonObj.push(tempObj)
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObj)))
//Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If You cannot do it with:

```js
var map = new Map(JSON.parse(str))
```

Try do it using:

```js
vat map = JSON.parse(str);
```

Eventually try:

```js
var map = new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(str)));
```