# Typescript Map in Object to Json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have class:

```
export class Widget {
  public id: any;
  public name: string;
  public position: number;
  public height: number;
  public width: number;
  public type: string;
  public params: Map<string, string>;
...
}
```

and I want to stringify object of that class, but I always get empty params...
I tried with:

`JSON.stringify(widget)` - empty params map `{}`

I also try to separate params from class:

`JSON.stringify([...widget.params])` but I got:

```
TS2461: Type 'Map<string, string>' is not an array type.
```

Comment: @jcalz question and choosen answer are more than 2 years old. It that still relevant?

Comment: @ideaboxer question and choosen answer are more than 2 years old. It that still relevant?

Comment: Can you still convert a `Map` to an array and serialize it?  Sure.

Answer (score -2):

The existing solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918232/how-do-i-persist-a-es6-map-in-localstorage-or-elsewhere) is still correct.

Do you want some kind of drop-in replacement for [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) that works with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) values?  You'd need to write it yourself.

Both functions take an optional parameter (`replacer` for `JSON.stringify()` and `reviver` for `JSON.parse()`) that allow you to customize how JavaScript objects are converted to and from JSON.  Here's a possibility:

```
const JSONWithMap = (mapIdentifier: string = "SerializedES6Map!!") => ({

  stringify(
    value: any,
    replacer?: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | (number | string)[] | null,
    space?: string | number
  ): string {

    let innerReplacer: (key: string, value: any) => any;
    if ((typeof replacer === 'undefined') || (replacer === null)) {
      innerReplacer = (k, v) => v;
    } else if (Array.isArray(replacer)) {
      innerReplacer = (k, v) => replacer.indexOf(k) >= 0 ? v : void 0;
    } else {
      innerReplacer = replacer;
    }

    let outerReplacer = function(this: any, key: string, value: any) {
      if (value instanceof Map) {        
        value = { [mapIdentifier]: Array.from(value.entries()) };
      }
      return innerReplacer.call(this, key, value);
    }

    return JSON.stringify(value, outerReplacer, space);

  },

  parse(text: string, reviver?: (key: any, value: any) => any): any {
    let innerReviver: (key: string, value: any) => any;
    if (typeof reviver === 'undefined' || reviver === null) {
      innerReviver = (k, v) => v;
    } else {
      innerReviver = reviver;
    }
    let outerReviver = function(this: any, key: string, value: any) {
      if ((typeof value !== 'undefined') && (Array.isArray(value[mapIdentifier]))) {
        return new Map(value[mapIdentifier]);
      }
      return innerReviver.call(this, key, value);
    }
    return JSON.parse(text, outerReviver);
  }
});
```

The function `JSONWithMap()` takes an optional string parameter for marking when a `Map` is being serialized and deserialized, and it defaults to `"SerializedES6Map!!"` which is hopefully something you will not use in other objects.  Its `stringify()` method acts just like `JSON.stringify()` except it also converts `Map`s to an object with a single key whose value is the serialized array of entries, and its `parse()` method acts just like `JSON.parse()` except it recognizes those serialized `Map` objects and deserializes them into `Map`s.

You can use it like this:

```
declare const widget: Widget; // some widget instance
const JSONM = JSONWithMap(); // use default identifier
const widgetJSON = JSONM.stringify(widget); // serialize
const deserializedWidget = JSONM.parse(widgetJSON); // deserialize into plain JS object
const rehydratedWidget = Object.assign(new Widget(), deserializedWidget); // actually make instance of class from plain JS object
```

---

Note I say "you'd need to write it yourself" and then hand you an implementation.  Well the implementation has not been tested except for very briefly, so you need to thoroughly test it, do something custom for your `Widget` class that isn't a drop-in replacement for `JSON.stringify()`, or write it yourself.

Good luck.