# From JS Object to JSON Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

Consider the following TypeScript class:

```
export class Spot {

    public flight:number;

    public dateAndTimes:Map<string,string>

    public unitCost:number;

    constructor(){
        this.flight=0;
        this.dateAndTimes= new Map<string,string>();
        this.unitCost=0;
    }
}
```

How can I convert the Spot object to JSON?

I try `JSON.stringify(spot)`, but the attribute `dateAndTimes` it's serialized as empty... for example:

```
"spot": {
 'flight':2,
  {},
 'unitCost':3500
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess your real problem is "How to convert Map to JSON". In that case it's already answered - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map (which will provide you a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918232/how-do-i-persist-a-es6-map-in-localstorage-or-elsewhere)

Comment: @mykhailo.romaniuk Thank you very much for your comment, but my real problem is that I need the whole object including the map attribute  serialized in json once

Comment: Don't use a map for that it's not helping you.

Comment: I agree with @AluanHaddad you can use a normal js object (typescript `any`). You will save this problem for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the MDN documentation for [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description):

> - All the other Object instances (including Map, Set, WeakMap, and WeakSet) will have only their enumerable properties serialized.

As a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can have any type for keys and values then even if you were able to stringify it the JSON spec does not account for any types outside of ["objects, arrays, numbers, strings, booleans, and null"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#JavaScript_and_JSON_differences). Therefore if any of the keys or values of the `Map` are not of those types then it would not be allowed by the specification.

That last point is extremely important as even if a Map was somehow serialized to JSON but included any type of key or value not of the aforementioned allowed types then it is not determinable how a parser would process the resultant JSON back into an object. If it is not necessary to use a Map then I would recommend using a plain object for this to avoid this issue completely.

Note that it is also not possible to roll your own [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters) function for the `JSON.stringify` method to handle that functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I would like to see an example in code .. how could the replacer create

Comment: Not all keys of a `Map` are symbols. The keys are ignored because they are on the prototype

Comment: @AlejoDev Apologies, I meant to say it *is not possible* to use a replacer function to do so as included in the original quote. Updated to clarify that.

Comment: then...it is impossible to serialize a javascript object that contains a map as an attribute?... I believe there must be a way

Comment: @AlejoDev I updated the answer to clarify the issue. If possible I would recommend using a simple object rather than a Map to avoid it. It *might* be possible to use [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) in this case but I am uncertain of that. It also does not resolve the greater issue outlined above.