# TypeError: val.set is not a function (JS Map())

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ionic4, capacitor

I'm having this issue where I'm executing `val.set(key, value)` and is throwing a type error `TypeError: val.set is not a function` in the file `vendor-es2015.js`.

The code (simplified):

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


map = new Map();

this.storage.set('sth', map);

this.storage.get('sth').then((val) => {
    val.set(key, value); //TypeError, returns { } insead of a map.
});
```

The interesting thing is that this works fine in browsers, but when it's compiled to Android with Capacitor, this error is thrown.

*tsconfig.json*

```
"target": "es2015",
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
]
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to see what the `val` is instead, if it is not the `Map` you expect?

Comment: @Bergi Oh, yes I forgot to mention. Instead of Map object I get returned in browser, I get a classic empty {} object.

Comment: I’m wondering if maybe Ionic Storage on devices doesn’t support storing Map somehow? Would that even be possibe?

Comment: Seems likely. I don't know ionic, but have a look at [How do I persist a ES6 Map in localstorage (or elsewhere)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28918232/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/storage#working-with-json) says :

> Storage works on Strings only. However, storing JSON blobs is easy:
>   just JSON.stringify the object before calling set, then JSON.parse the
>   value returned from get. See the example below for more details.

Might look like this (updated with [help from Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53461519/1347953)):

```
const mapStr = JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.entries()));
this.storage.set('sth', mapStr);

this.storage.get('sth').then((val) => {
    const theMap = new Map(JSON.parse(val));
    theMap.set(key, value);
});
```

Comment: Yes, except that's not [how to JSON.stringify an ES6 Map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29085197/1048572)

Comment: So maybe it's not safe to store a map in Storage.

Comment: I just found this interesting answer ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/53461519/1347953

Comment: Guess how I knew to link that question :-)

Comment: I was just about to suggest to remap it. Will try now. Also, the documentation you linked is not the same storage as what I'm using. [This one](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage) is.

Comment: @jaka_music sorry  I got confused because the post is tagged capacitor. BTW why not use the Capacitor one?

Comment: No particular reason. Been using it in all projects and have gotten used to it.

Comment: OK :) I'm just trying to move away from Cordova plugins, especially when Capacitor provides an embedded solution.