# How can I use a Map with pinia/vue3

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I am trying to set values in a map stored in a pinia store (persisted into localstorage)

in this minimal (non) working example pushing elements into a list works fine but adding a element into a Map does not persist.

### `component.vue`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useStore } from "./store"

const store = useStore()
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <button
      @click="store.createA"
      >
      Create new Array item
    </button>
    <ul v-if="store.array.length > 0">
      <li v-for="(item) in store.array">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul><br/>
    <button
      @click="store.createO"
      >
      Create Map Object
    </button>
    <ul v-if="store.mapObj.size > 0">
      <li v-for="(item) in store.mapObj">
        {{ item[1] }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </main>
</template>
```

### `store.ts`

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia"

export const useStore = defineStore({
  id: "character-manager",
  state: () => ({ array: [] as Array<{key: string, value: string }>,
                  mapObj: new Map() as Map<string,string>}),
  actions: {
    createA() {
      this.array.push({key: "key", value: "value"})
    },
    createO() {
      this.mapObj.set("key", "value")
    },
  },
  persist: {
    enabled: true,
    strategies: [{ storage: localStorage }],
  },
})
```

Comment: couldnt reproduce it to be honest,

Comment: have you checked localstorage, the map insert seems to be working, but it is not persisted in my browser

Comment: a yes sorry didnt check the localStorage. it is reproducible now. let me re-check it

Comment: it seems difficult. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918232/how-do-i-persist-a-es6-map-in-localstorage-or-elsewhere

Comment: maybe use another structure?

Comment: https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate#non-primitive-types-are-not-persisted I just found this, and will try that approach later

Comment: I've tried, without success, so i switched to an array of key/value pairs. not the nicest to use or most efficient. but it does the job well, and my scenario doesn't have to deal with a lot of elements