# Python json loads error JSONDecodeError Expecting Value

Tags: python, json, string

I have read just about every json loads out there:
[Python json.loads fails with `ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 33 (char 33)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295439/python-json-loads-fails-with-valueerror-invalid-control-character-at-line-1-c)
[Python Json lower case nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129396/python-json-lower-case-nan)
[JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)
[Single versus double quotes in json loads in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347047/single-versus-double-quotes-in-json-loads-in-python)

I have replaced single quotes with double quotes, I have changed nan to NaN, I have checked for carriage returns, I encoded it as utf-8.  Still I am getting an error when trying `json.loads` or `ast.literval_eval`.

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 33 (char 32)
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000016583978160>
```

The string starts like this

```
temp3[:50]
>>> '{"firstOTDriveAlreadyHappened": False, "NeedsHomeA'
```

Any ideas?

____SOLUTION___

Mentioned in a comment, but I had to make the following maps:

```
temp3 = temp3.replace('False', 'false')
temp3 = temp3.replace('True', 'true')
temp3 = temp3.replace('None', 'null')
temp3 = temp3.replace('nan', 'NaN')
temp3 = temp3.replace("'", '"')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: _Any ideas?_ Yes -- show us the full json string.

Comment: I don't mind if you share the full json to check for inconsistency

Comment: In json `False` is spelled `false`.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you I didn't see that anywhere - and why are the other comments so passive aggresive, that is a minimally reproducible example and sometimes people can't provide entire strings because of sensitive info

Comment: For all future newbies to `json`, the requisite reading is: http://json.org/

Comment: Nobody mentioned it but the problem lays in the source of that "JSON". It should be fixed there and not by shaky string replacement on the receiver side.