# Store NaN in Firebase with Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to store the value `NaN` in Firebase.

Here is my setup:

The value is `let varname = Double.nan;`

I am setting the value by calling `FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "test").setValue(varname);`

But I am getting the following error:

> 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store NaN at path:
>   varname.'

Is there a different way I should be saving this `NaN`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data in Firebase Databases are [stored as JSON](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), and JSON [cannot contain `NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424034/2054731).

The best you can do is to store `"NaN"` or some other value that you translate to `NaN` on read. (A bit impractical, so perhaps you should reconsider whether you really want `NaN` in your database.)