# How do you check for nan in python jmespath?

Tags: python, nan, jmespath

Assume `import jmespath`.  Let's say I have some data like:

```
In [3]: data=[{'foo':10}, {'foo':float('nan')}, {'foo':32}]

In [4]: data
Out[4]: [{'foo': 10}, {'foo': nan}, {'foo': 32}]
```

I want to use jmespath to count the number of nodes that are nan. I can't seem to get it to.  I can count the non-nan nodes like so:

```
jmespath.search('length([?@.foo.abs(@) >= `0`])',data)
```

I have tried comparing to `nan` and `NaN` but that doesn't work, and frankly it shouldn't because nan doesn't equal nan. However, there is no is_nan() function that I can see.  I suppose I could convert to string and then compare them? That seems like a last resort. Is there some is_nan I don't see documented?

Comment: Maybe dumb idea depending on your use-case, but you could subtract from the data length the non-nan length (change `>` to `>=` though).

Comment: @wim i meant to have >=, which i edited.  it's not that straightfoward to do arithmetic in jmespath as far as i can tell but i thought about that. I need to look into if arithmetic is a thing

Comment: JSON does not know NAN: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1423081/7311767

Comment: @Stephen Raunch, that link seems to claim that its treated as null but interestingly there is an is_null() method in jmespath, but it didn't not identify nans as null.  I think ultimately i will try to add a custom function into the language

Answer (score 0):

### Context

- python 2.x or python 3.x
- jmespath query

### Problem

- how to construct a query that counts the instances of `nan` (not a number)

### Solution

- use Jmespath `not-expression` [! (exclaimation point)](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#not-expressions) in conjunction with the `abs()` function
- use jmespath `length()` function to count the results

### Example

```
jmespath.compile('''[*].foo|[? !(abs(@) >= `0`)]|length([*])''').search(data)
```

### Details

- Jmespath `type()` function treats `nan` as `number`
- Using `not-expression` in combination with `abs(@) greater-than or equal-to zero` returns true for `nan`

### Pitfalls

- Jmespath errors out with `invalid type for value` if an incompatible type is passed into `abs()` (such as string).