# Are null and Infinity interchangeable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm setting `max` to `Infinity` on this object:

```
let RANGE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS: any = { min: 0, max: Infinity };
console.log(RANGE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS); // {min: 0, max: null}
```

When the `RANGE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` object is logged, it logs `null` for the `max` property.

[Here's the Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yh7ny4)

Also this will log `true`:

```
console.log(RANGE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS.max === Infinity);
```

So are `Infinity` and `null` interchangeable?

Comment: `RANGE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS.max === null` returns `false` in your stackblitz.

Comment: @jabaa Good Observation.  I can't always believe my eyes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the same code in a snippet you can run in your browser. As you can see, `Infinity` and `null` are not equal.

```js
let RANGE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS = { min: 0, max: Infinity };
console.log(RANGE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
console.log('strict equality', Infinity === null);
console.log('loose equality', Infinity == null);
```

Comment: It produces `null` in the stackblitz.

Answer (score 5):

No, they’re not.

Normally, `console.log(…)` called with an object, prints the object intact:

[image]

```js
const obj = { min: 0, max: Infinity };

console.log(obj);
```

In the case of StackBlitz, there’s probably a call to `JSON.stringify(…)` somewhere down there, which messes things up (which is sad, IMO):

[image]

Comment: Yup, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423081/json-left-out-infinity-and-nan-json-status-in-ecmascript for further context